# <h:commandLink target=“_blank” only after validation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I used the h:commandLink target="_blank" method to get the new tab, but it shows the

validation errors in the new tab. I want it to only open the new tab if the validation is passed.
 So, is there a way to validate and open a new window only if validation passes?
 without using javascript or jquery.
 thanks

i have tried in h:commandButton but it opens in same tab

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you can't do without javascript, because the `target` attribute forces the **browser** to open a new tab/window immediately, followed by the server request.